# Does every thermal printer has ability to open cash drawer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, point-of-sale

One thing I have tried to search before in the past is how to make some of the POS peripheral devices work with a web based POS app. The answer that I found mostly was as web apps are not being executed on the machine as such but rather in the browser with limited access to features, it is not possible. Although there can be a large range of Hardware devices involved in POS applications the most common ones include Printer, Cash Register and Bar Code Scanner. Printer and Bar Code scanner can work with any app but Cash Register could not from what I understood in the past. 
Now I stumbled upon this article which explains how you can configure your Cash Register to open when a print is sent to the printer.

http://support.vendhq.com/hc/en-us/articles/201378340-Configure-a-Star-TSP100-or-TSP143-printer-to-open-the-cash-drawer-Windows-Mac-

This article recomends a specific model of printer but my question is that can this behavior be achieved with any printer or is it a printer specific feature. If this is a feature, is there a common name for this mechanism?

Comment: I believe Epson printers have this ability too and they are probably the most widely used printers in the POS market.  [This](http://support.epostraders.co.uk/support-files/documents/27/Ya8-EpsonDrawerKick.pdf) article may help, you can fire the cash drawer using ESC POS commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any specific name for this feature but what I do understand is that a lot of Receipt printers come with ports for cash drawers, so it is kind of a feature of these printers. For reference you can check the answer on this link

http://www.omniprintinc.com/faqs.html

> What is a receipt printer?
>
> A receipt printer is necessary for all point of sale systems. There
>   are one or two cash drawer ports on the back of your receipt printer
>   for direct attachment. The receipt printer and cash drawer will share
>   a single port on your PC. You have several options to choose from when
>   choosing a pos receipt printer including thermal printers, impact
>   printers, automatic paper cutters, parallel or serial ports, printer
>   speed, and printer resolution.

Comment: I never quite understood when people down vote without giving an reason? I tried to write a very specific question about something that is confusing. I also shared whatever reference links I have, still if you feel that there is something missing then please mention in the comments at least before down voting so that I can avoid it in the future, otherwise it's note really constructive.

Comment: Some people downvote answers to bad questions even if the answer was good.  I'm not very experienced with the topic of this question but this is something that some people do.

Answer (score 1):

Simple proof:  I have an industrial printer here.  While I'm not using it in thermal mode it has one.  There's no cash drawer around for it to open.  Thus clearly thermal printers that can't open cash drawers exist.

Comment: Then is this a special feature in some printers if so is there any name for this?

Comment: @AfrazAli I think you're confusing thermal printers with cash registers.  The printer next to me is an industrial label printer, it can run direct thermal mode or can print with a ribbon onto ordinary label stock.  It's meant for use on a factory floor, not a point of sale situation.

Comment: I am referring to the Thermal printers that are used to print receipts in Retail stores mate as referred to in the link that I have posted.

Comment: I am aware cash register is a separate hardware but it seems that there is port in the back of the printer where you can just plug the cash register and configure the printer in a way that it opens cash register when it prints. Hope that removes any confusion.

Comment: @AfrazAli There's no such port on mine.  What I have is an industrial label printer (it weighs over 30# with no media loaded).  Thermal printers cover a lot more than just POS receipt printers.

Comment: Oh ok, Thanks for the clarification, I guess I should have been more specific about the Retail receipts thermal printer.